# libgps.so is missing in compilation on android

Tags: android, gps

i made a few changes in gps and compiled it to generate libgps.so, but no such file is generated after compilation. i am using froyo branch for this. The compilation was successful and system.img was also generated.
where can i find this file or how to generate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, gps.cpp is compiled in to `libhardware_legacy.so` and not `libgps.so`. If you want to make libgps.so with your changes, you will have to modify `Android.mk` in hardware/libhardware_legacy/gps.

Comment: ok thanks. i did strings on libhardware_legacy and i found my code.